# NativeScript Ios

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript

Trying to run the iOS emulator on native script but it keeps failing to open the app specifically...

Here is the error it keeps giving me:

> Command failed: /bin/sh -c ruby -e "require 'xcodeproj'; Xcodeproj::Config.new('/Users/nanle/Documents/development/groceryTest/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/plugins-debug.xcconfig').merge(Xcodeproj::Config.new('/Users/nanle/Documents/development/groceryTest/sample-Groceries/app/App_Resources/iOS/build.xcconfig')).save_as(Pathname.new('/Users/nanle/Documents/development/groceryTest/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/plugins-debug.xcconfig'))"
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj (LoadError)
>       from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>       from -e:1:in `'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing xcodeproj, try install it with

> sudo gem install xcodeproj